# use structure declared in main.go in other package

Tags: go

I have a structure declared in `main.go` as shown below:

```
type Organization struct {
    ID    string `json:"id"`
    Count int    `json:"count"` //node count
}
```

I have a package named `configuration` and have a function like this:

```
func foo(org main.Organization) {

}
```

The issue is I am not able to access `main.Organization`. Is there any way to access struct declared in `main.go` in another package?

Comment: Why not put `Organization` in a library package?

Comment: library package? can you explain what library package is?

Comment: Another package that `main` imports. Just like `configuration` will be

Comment: Is this  a restriction of GO ?

Comment: Why can't you declare a struct in main and use it in other package?

Comment: I assume `main.go` is also `package main`?

Comment: yes `main.go` is package main

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not possible to import `package main` except in certain rare circumstances.

I found this explanation on a [mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/Golang-nuts/frh9zQPEjUk) dated back last year.

> However importing a main package in another main package works.
>   To summarize:
>
> 1) importing a main package in a external test is supported
>   2) importing a main package in a main package is supported
>   3) ***importing a main package in a non main package is not supported***
>
> This seems reasonable to me, however AFAIK it is not documented.

From the [language spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec)

> A complete program is created by linking a single, ***unimported*** package called the main package with all the packages it imports, transitively. The main package must have package name main and declare a function main that takes no arguments and returns no value.

(emphasis mine in both quotes)

Answer (score 4):

You can't import the main package from other packages in go(except in certain situations, such as a test case).

Instead create a new directory e.g. named `mytypes` , In this folder create the file `types.go` which would look like:

```
package mytypes
type Organization struct {
    ID    string `json:"id"`
    Count int    `json:"count"` //node count
}
```

Wherever you want to use this struct, such as in main an , you `import "mytypes"` and use the `Organization` struct as `mytypes.Organization`

Alternatively, you move the `Organization` struct to your `configuration` package and use `configuration.Organization` in your main.