# Using a logger that is initialized in main in other parts of codebase

Tags: go, logging

I am struggling with how to use a [zap](https://pkg.go.dev/go.uber.org/zap). In the docs, they provide a few examples on how to [configure](https://pkg.go.dev/go.uber.org/zap#example-package-BasicConfiguration) a logger and how to use a [preset](https://pkg.go.dev/go.uber.org/zap#example-package-Presets). However, I do not understand how one is supposed to use the logger that is initialized in `main.go`, which lives in `cmd/server/server.go`. According to [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52418430/use-structure-declared-in-main-go-in-other-package), and several others, one cannot import from the `main` package outside of the package. So, based on the Zap examples, how am I supposed to use the logger in say `pkg/endpoint/my_requests` (`pkg` is at same level as `cmd`)? I have not been able to find any explicit examples (even unrelated to zap) on how to accomplish something like this; yet, I am certain this is a very simple question.

Comment: Why the vote to close? I genuinely am struggling with this problem and need help.

Comment: A common way of doing this is to declare all the shared variables in a package (like pkg/log) , and then initialize those variables in main. All other packages then use the logger from pkg/log.

Comment: @BurakSerdar In Navid's answer below, he has to initialize `logger` in every file. When you say "All other packages then use the logger from pkg/log", it doesn't sound like you have to initialize it at the top of every file.

Comment: The answer is not "initializing the logger" at every file, it is simply getting an instance of a logger. What I meant to say is very similar to the answer below: A separate log package that you initialize from main, then every package gets their loggers from that package.

Answer (score 7):

I personally favor treating it as any other normal dependency and pass it where it is need it

```
package foo

type Bar struct {
    Logger logger.Logger
}

func (b *Bar) Something() {
    b.Logger.Debug("starting something")
}

func DoSomething(logger logger.Logger) {
    b := Bar{Logger: logger}
    b.Something()
}
```

Anything that involves an init function is basically a global variable

I also tend to use an abstraction over any logger that I use, and give the zero value a no-op behavior (doesn't log anything), especially helpful while testing, the downside it's a bit slower since all method are not a pointer receiver and require a copy and that I have to define the same methods (in fact I abstract the sugared version so I don't import zap on my packages)

```
package logger

import "go.uber.org/zap"

type Logger struct {
    zap *zap.Logger
}

func Must(logger *Logger, err error) *Logger {
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    return logger
}

func NewLogger(logFile string) (*Logger, error) {
    zap.NewProductionConfig()
    config := zap.NewProductionConfig()
    config.OutputPaths = []string{"stdout", "./logs/" + logFile}
    logger, err := config.Build(zap.AddCaller())
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }   
    return &Logger{zap: logger}, err
}

func (l Logger) Debug(msg string, fields ...zap.Field) {
    l.writer().Debug(msg, fields...)
}

func (l Logger) Info(msg string, fields ...zap.Field) {
    l.writer().Info(msg, fields...)
}
// define all the methdos

var noOpLogger = zap.NewNop()

func (l Logger) writer() *zap.Logger {
    if l.zap == nil {
        return noOpLogger
    }
    return l.zap
}
```

The zero value no-op logger is safe for concurrent use and the logger doesn't get in the middle anymore during testing

```
var b Bar
b.Something() // no panics
```

Comment: I use the first method (I prefer passing it down the stack explicitly). Do you find any downsides to this? Sometimes I find myself passing it down quite a few layers... and it makes me think maybe this is the _right_ place to use a global?

Comment: @Christian Over the years I've lowered "my verbosity", and now I mostly log only at the most external layers of my application; request handlers, message consumers... usually with help of middlewares or base structs, so it's rare for me to pass the logger many layers down.
For example, I almost never log in the domain code, I bubble up any errors or info as results that I want to log, same for generating monitoring metrics too.

Imo people tend to flood the logs with debug entries, that are only useful while developing, and never checked again, I rather use the debugger

Comment: @hmoragrega Shouldn't the receivers be pointers? As in `func (l *Logger) Debug(msg string....`

Comment: @TheRealFakeNews you can define them as pointer receivers, but it's not necessary, it will depend on your logger implementation; does it have to mutate the fields? how big is the struct? as it is in the example, the size is the same for both options but if the logger struct grows a pointer receiver may be more performant, but then you need to be more careful.. is a matter of tradeoffs.

Answer (score 4):

A good idea would be to create a package responsible for the logger or just a package like "config" or "settings" to handle the global configurations like logger.

I do use zap in my projects and I usually have a package named logger which provides a base method called `NewLogger` which I call from my other packages to create a package-specific logger when my packages generate a lot of logs and they are pretty big. In rather smaller projects, I just initialize the logger in the logger package and call it from outside.

```
// /my-project/pkg/logging/logging.go
func NewLogger(logFile string) *zap.Logger {
    zap.NewProductionConfig()
    config := zap.NewProductionConfig()
    config.OutputPaths = []string{"stdout", "./logs/" + logFile}
    logger, err := config.Build(zap.AddCaller())
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    return logger
}
```

And then use it in other packages:

```
// /my-project/pkg/a/a.go

package a

var logger *zap.Logger

func init() {
    logger = logging.NewLogger("a.log")
}

func MyFunction() {
    logger.Info("log from package a to a.log")
}
```

another package:

```
// /my-project/pkg/b/b.go

package b

var logger *zap.Logger

func init() {
    logger = logging.NewLogger("b.log")
}

func MyFunction() {
    logger.Info("log from package b to b.log")
}
```

You can also initialize the logger directly in your packages but having your logger in a separate package helps you change the configuration or the entire logger whenever you want without the need to make changes everywhere.

You can also add more methods and helpers to your logger package to unify your logs or just make your life easier for logging stuff.

Comment: Does `var logger *zap.Logger` have to be included in every file or is there some way to make that global across the entire project?

Comment: Also, is it ideal that we are creating a new logger for every file? I am concerned if that is safe for concurrent use.

Comment: You don't have to. You can initialize it in the logger package and just call it from there like this: `logging.logger.Info("log")`. Buy having it separate in each package has its own benefits. And it won't cause a problem for concurrent use. You can even configure each one differently so that it flushes logs at different rates. How to initialize logger comes to your needs and how you feel comfortable.